# Link rendering issue while server side markdownsharp conversion and sanitization - how to get the same output as pagedown does

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, markdown, wmd, markdownsharp, pagedown

I'm using [pagedown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown) editor. The code I'm using for gerating the preview is following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var previewConverter = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
    var editor = new Markdown.Editor(previewConverter);
    editor.run();
});
```

While I enter some text to the input:

[image]

the dynamically generated output preview will be as expected, and looks following:

[image]

The content (the pure entered text shown below) is then saved to database:

```
"http://www.google.com\n\n<script>alert('hi');</script>\n\n[google][4]\n\n\n  [1]: http://www.google.com"
```

On the server side, before the page is rendered, I'm converting this fetched from database text, using this [markdownsharp library v1.13.0.0](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/). After conversion, I'm sanitizing the html using Jeff Atwood's code, which I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136084/sanitizing-html-using-jeff-atwoods-example):

```
    private static Regex _tags = new Regex("<[^>]*(>|$)",
    RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Compiled);
private static Regex _whitelist = new Regex(@"
    ^</?(b(lockquote)?|code|d(d|t|l|el)|em|h(1|2|3)|i|kbd|li|ol|p(re)?|s(ub|up|trong|trike)?|ul)>$|
    ^<(b|h)r\s?/?>$",
    RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
private static Regex _whitelist_a = new Regex(@"
    ^<a\s
    href=""(\#\d+|(https?|ftp)://[-a-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;\(\)]+)""
    (\stitle=""[^""<>]+"")?\s?>$|
    ^</a>$",
    RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
private static Regex _whitelist_img = new Regex(@"
    ^<img\s
    src=""https?://[-a-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;\(\)]+""
    (\swidth=""\d{1,3}"")?
    (\sheight=""\d{1,3}"")?
    (\salt=""[^""<>]*"")?
    (\stitle=""[^""<>]*"")?
    \s?/?>$",
    RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);


/// <summary>
/// sanitize any potentially dangerous tags from the provided raw HTML input using 
/// a whitelist based approach, leaving the "safe" HTML tags
/// CODESNIPPET:4100A61A-1711-4366-B0B0-144D1179A937
/// </summary>
public static string Sanitize(string html)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(html)) return html;

    string tagname;
    Match tag;

    // match every HTML tag in the input
    MatchCollection tags = _tags.Matches(html);
    for (int i = tags.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        tag = tags[i];
        tagname = tag.Value.ToLowerInvariant();

        if(!(_whitelist.IsMatch(tagname) || _whitelist_a.IsMatch(tagname) || _whitelist_img.IsMatch(tagname)))
        {
            html = html.Remove(tag.Index, tag.Length);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("tag sanitized: " + tagname);
        }
    }

    return html;
}
```

The conversion and sanitization process is following::

```
    var md = new MarkdownSharp.Markdown();            
    var unsafeHtml = md.Transform(content);
    var safeHtml = Sanitize(unsafeHtml);
    return new HtmlString(safeHtml);
```

`unsafeHtml` contains

```
"<p>http://www.google.com</p>\n\n<script>alert('hi');</script>\n\n<p><a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a></p>\n"
```

`safeHtml` contains

```
"<p>http://www.google.com</p>\n\nalert('hi');\n\n<p><a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a></p>\n"
```

This renders to:

[image]

So sanitization and the second link were converted as expected. Unfortunately, the first link is not a link anymore, just text. How to fix this ?

Maybe better approach is not to use server side conversion, but just use javascript to render the markdown text on the page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Markdown.Converter.js` we can find `_DoAutoLinks(text)` function. There is section which automatically add `<` and `>` around unadorned raw hyperlinks, and then autolink anything like `<http://example.com>`. This is why

```
http://www.google.com
```

will be first converted to:

```
<http://www.google.com>
```

and then to:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>
```

My temporary workaround is doing something similiar at the c# side:

```
var unsafeHtml = DoAutolinks(md.Transform(content));

private static string DoAutolinks(string content)
{            
    /* url pattern - from msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx */
    const string url = @"(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?";
    const string pattern = @"<p>(?<url>" + url + ")</p>";
    var result = Regex.Replace(content, pattern, "<p><a href=\"${url}\">${url}</a></p>");
    return result;
}
```

Should such functionality - responsible for unadorned links conversion, be included in markdownsharp ?

Comment: This functionality *is* included -- it's just turned off by default: http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/browse/MarkdownSharp/Markdown.cs#97

Comment: Thanks for the effort to read this question after 4 months ;] But still good to know. Regards.